# Iterating through secondary indices

Tags: multi-index

I have a table with some secondary indices. I want to iterate through the rows whose values are `act >= 1` and discard the rest.

So:

```
table holders(_self, _self.value);
auto index_by_act = holders.get_index<"byact"_n>();

for (auto i = index_by_act.lower_bound(1); i != index_by_act.end(); i++)
```

This still iterates over the rows with 0 value. If I get the same command with cleos:

```
cleos get table --index 3 --key-type i64 -L 1 contract contract table
```

I get the right list (no rows with `act > 0`). So I must be doing something wrong and I don't understand what exactly.

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the problem, I'll put it here so the next guy won't do the same.

I was zeroing the act value inside the loop, so somehow the iterator kept hitting the same row with a value < 0. The solution was to change to a while loop and instead of incrementing i, get a new lower bound (it will move the iterator forward anyway).

Not sure if this is very cpu-expensive, but it definitely does the trick.

**Edit** Here's how I made it work:

```
table holders(_self, _self.value);
auto index_by_act = holders.get_index<"byact"_n>();
auto i = index_by_act.lower_bound(0);

while (i != index_by_act.end())
{
// some logic here
i = index_by_act.lower_bound(1);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a code example for future users who find this question?

Comment: Hi! Sure (I was writing on my phone and that's why I didn't add some code). Will edit the comment